# How to retrieve Java 9 module dependencies in a Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependencies, java-9, modular

in this [short article](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-visualize-jigsaw-module-graph) there is a Spring boot application (for visualizing Java 9 platform modules and their dependencies) implemented.

How do I retrieve only non-platform modules from my custom Spring boot application to visualize their dependencies?

I am able to retrieve the data from a standard standalone application in this way:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main().getModules();
}

public Map<String, HashSet<?>> getModules() {
    var nodes = new HashSet<Node>();
    var edges = new HashSet<Edge>();

    fillNodeAndEdges2(nodes, edges);

    Map<String, HashSet<?>> mapa1 = Map.of("nodes", nodes, "edges", edges);

    Iterator<Entry<String, HashSet<?>>> it = mapa1.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Entry<String, HashSet<?>> entry = it.next();
        System.out.println(entry);
    }

    return mapa1;
}

private void fillNodeAndEdges2(HashSet<Node> nodes, HashSet<Edge> edges) {
    Module myModule = this.getClass().getModule();
    ModuleDescriptor myModuleDescriptor = myModule.getDescriptor();

    Set<Requires> requires = myModuleDescriptor.requires();

    String moduleName = myModule.getName();
    for (Requires require : requires) {
        System.out.println("require:" + require);
        nodes.add(new Node(moduleName));
        edges.add(new Edge(moduleName, require.name()));
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I am not able to retrieve the same list of modules with dependencies from Spring boot application. I tried the following code, but myModule is UNNAMED, so its ModuleDescriptor is null. Why is my module UNNAMED? The module should be explicit since the project contains module-info.java file:

`private void fillNodeAndEdges2(HashSet nodes, HashSet edges) {
        Map beans = ApplicationContext.getBeansWithAnnotation(Service.class);
        Object bean = beans.values().iterator().next();
        Module myModule = bean.getClass().getModule();
        System.out.println("bean.getClass():" + bean.getClass()); //IT NICELY RETURNS THE CORRECT BEAN-CLASS
        System.out.println("myModule:"+ myModule);
        ModuleDescriptor myModuleDescriptor = myModule.getDescriptor();
        if (myModuleDescriptor == null) {
            System.out.println("myModuleDescriptor == NULL");
            return;
        }`

```
    Set<Requires> requires = myModuleDescriptor.requires();

    String moduleName = myModule.getName();
    for (Requires require : requires) {
        System.out.println("require:" + require);
        nodes.add(new Node(moduleName));
        edges.add(new Edge(moduleName, require.name()));
    }
}
```

module-info.java looks like as follows:

```
module module.graph {
requires spring.beans;
requires spring.context;
requires spring.web;
requires spring.boot.autoconfigure;
requires spring.boot;
requires spring.boot.starter.web;
requires java.base;
}
```

Maven dependencies are as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.kodedu.modulegraph</groupId>
<artifactId>module.graph</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>module.graph</name>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>10</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>module.graph</finalName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And complete project is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1btjvWT58pqCROyqg8zD_WK5RssIM8_ew)

I am not sure whether Spring boot is already capable to work with Java-9-modules.